# Mat-table performance issues - once the table has loaded, it freezes the page

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, mat-table

I have a mat-table that has over 150 rows, which doesn't seem like much but it completely freezes the page (especially if I have the developer console open).

To set the table data I use an input getter and setter (the reason being that it then allows me to make changes in the parent component and the child component will listen.)

```
@Input()
get data() {
    return this.dataSource;
}
set data(tableData: any) {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.data = tableData;
    // moment dates cant be sorted by mat-table: this is their 
    // recommendation to convert it to timestamp to be sorted 
    // (still displays as moment date tho :D)
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
        switch (property) {
            case 'momentDueDate': return new Date(item.momentDueDate);
            default: return item[property];
        }
    };
}
```

The data itself loads relatively quick, however, as soon as I click anything on the page, the page freezes. This even includes trying to change page using mat-pagination on the table.

In my parent component, my data is created by an observable using combineLAtest like so:

```
this.combinedPaymentsAndfilters$ = combineLatest(
    [this.combinedPaymentDetails$,
        this.dateFilter$,
        this.dateToFrom.asObservable(),
        this.typeFilter$,
        this.sortFilter$, 
        this.isAdmin$]).pipe(
            tap(([payments, dateFilter, dateToFrom, type, sort, isAdmin]) => {
        this._router.navigate(['.'], {
            queryParams: {
                date: dateFilter,
                dateFrom: dateToFrom.date_from,
                dateTo: dateToFrom.date_to,
                type: type, 
                order: sort
            },
            relativeTo: this._route,
            replaceUrl: true
        });
    }),
    map(([payments, dateFilter, dateToFrom, type, sort, isAdmin]) => {
        let combined = this.sortPayments(sort, payments);
        if (dateFilter !== 'all') {
            combined = this.filterByDate(payments, dateFilter, dateToFrom);
        }
        if (type !== 'all') {
            combined = combined.filter(
                (payment: any) => payment.paymentType === type);
        }
        this.paymentTitle = this.getViewValue(this.paymentTypeFilter, type);
        this.dateTitle = this.getViewValue(this.dateFilterType, dateFilter);
        return {
            combined,
            isAdmin
        };
    })
);
```

I also get the following chrome violations whilst in this component:

[image]

Other things I have tried:

So I have looked at a few similar things online, and people have recommended loading the data after the pagination etc (which you can see above I have). 
Others have also recommended using `AfterViewInit`, I have also tried this, but it still makes no difference. 
As a way of testing whether there was something else erroring in my code, I have also limited my firestore query to only return 5 items. Once I have done this, it works absolutely fine, which tells me the issue is definitely with the amount of data I am trying to display.

Any recommendations on improving this performance as currently, its unusable for production.

*EDIT* - The issue only really seems to happen when the chrome console is open

Comment: Most likely there's too much going on in Combined payments function. Try to reduce work into smaller async parts yeilding small but continuous results. You will be able to see areas to improve.

Comment: @JohnPeters Could you expand on that please? `Try to reduce work into smaller async parts yeilding small but continuous results`

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the answer of satanTime, if the combineLatest persists to be spammy even if `distinctUntilChanged`, you can use the operator [debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime) to force some milliseconds of silence and then get the last result.

Another angular list optimization is to use [trackBy](https://blog.eyas.sh/2019/10/use-trackby-in-angular-ngfor-loops-and-mattables).

Comment: @satanTime So, I have added a debounce to the end of the combineLatest, but the problem is once the data has loaded, when I try to change page on the mat-table pagination, there is a real lag - almost seems as if nothing is happening

Comment: it should be the first operator in the pipe of combineLatest, not the latest argument in it.

Comment: @satanTime Added to the start but still getting the same lag when changing pagination

Comment: I see, sad sad, what about distinctUntilChanged? does it have the same no effect?

Comment: @satanTime no effect, unfortunately! The problem is, it seems to work okay when js console is closed, but starts to lag when open!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213693/discussion-between-satantime-and-jm3s).

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would say that too many emits are happening in `combineLatest`.
Perhaps with the same data in case if its filter wasn't changed.

every emit can cause changes of pointers even data is the same and it can cause a new render of the table.

I would add [distinctUntilChanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged) as the first `pipe` operator to ensure that we really need to emit new value.

It's the implementation with `JSON.encode`.

```
.pipe(
   distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => JSON.encode(prev) !== JSON.encode(curr))
   ...
)
```

Then regardless of emits with the same values your pipe won't react until there's a real change.

Comment: Still having the same issue when implementing this! Thank you though

Comment: Let me know if it works, otherwise we can find a way how to debug it and fix slow places.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth - I ran into the same symptoms and it turned out that Chrome had an update pending in the background. So, if you also experience "*The issue only really seems to happen when the chrome console is open*" -- try to reboot Chrome to let the update complete. It worked for me.